# jQuery Clicking two buttons erroneously makes them disappear?

Tags: jquery, css, html, toggle

Here's something that is driving me crazy. I have two buttons (Hide/Show liked and Hide/Show disliked) that when clicked, toggle all liked posts or toggle all disliked posts.

My code works beautifully but there's a catch: If both buttons are "on" (the user wants to hide all liked AND all disliked), all the liked and disliked posts do in fact disappear... but so do the buttons!

Obviously, the buttons should not disappear under any circumstance. Can anyone point out why this is happening? Nowhere in my code am I toggling the div "mastercontrols" (which is where the buttons reside). Could this be a CSS issue? position of "mastercontrols" is relative. Variables likestatus and dislikestatus are global for a reason - they are used in other functions.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
likestatus = 1;
dislikestatus = 1;

//When Hide Liked checkbox clicked, toggle all liked posts.
$('#show_likes').on('click', function() {
    countlikes = $('[id^=post_].like').length;

    if (countlikes >0) {
        likestatus++;

        $('[id^=post_].like').toggle();

        if (likestatus % 2 == 0) {
            $('#hidelikedbtn').removeClass('hidelikedimgoff').addClass('hidelikedimgon');
        } else {
            $('#hidelikedbtn').removeClass('hidelikedimgon').addClass('hidelikedimgoff');
        }
    }

    return false;
});

//When Hide Disliked checkbox clicked, toggle all disliked posts.
$('#show_dislikes').on('click', function() {
    countdislikes = $('[id^=post_].dislike').length;

    if (countdislikes >0) {
        dislikestatus++;

        $('[id^=post_].dislike').toggle();

        if (dislikestatus % 2 == 0) {
            $('#hidedislikedbtn').removeClass('hidedislikedimgoff').addClass('hidedislikedimgon');
        } else {
            $('#hidedislikedbtn').removeClass('hidedislikedimgon').addClass('hidedislikedimgoff');
        }
    }

    return false;
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="mastercontrols">
<div id="show_likes" style="position:absolute;">
    <a id="hidelikedbtn" class="hidelikedimgoff" href="#"><span></span></a>
</div>

<div id="show_dislikes" style="position:absolute; right: 0em;">
    <a id="hidedislikedbtn" class="hidedislikedimgoff" href="#"><span></span></a>
</div>
</div>

<?php 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Posts") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )){ 
?>

<div id="post_<?php echo $row['contestID']; ?>" class="post">
<div id="post_<?php echo $row['contestID']; ?>_inside" class="inside">
    <b><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></b><br>
    <?php echo $row['Description']; ?><br>
</div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

CSS:

```
a.likeimgoff {
float: right;
background: url(images/entered.png) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.likeimgoff:active, a.likeimgoff:hover{
float: right;
background: url(images/entered.png) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.likeimgon {
float: right;
background: url(images/entered.png) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.likeimgon:active, a.likeimgon:hover{
float: right;
background: url(images/entered.png) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.dislikeimgoff {
float: right;
background: url(images/not-interested.png) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.dislikeimgoff:active, a.dislikeimgoff:hover{
float: right;
background: url(images/not-interested.png) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.dislikeimgon {
float: right;
background: url(images/not-interested.png) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

a.dislikeimgon:active, a.dislikeimgon:hover{
float: right;
background: url(images/not-interested.png) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 28px;
}

.inside {
position: relative;
padding: 0 0 7em 0;
}

#mastercontrols {
position: relative;
}

a.hidelikedimgoff {
float: left;
display: block;
background: url(images/entered.jpg) no-repeat top center;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
}

a.hidelikedimgon {
float: left;
display: block;
background: url(images/entered.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
}

a.hidedislikedimgoff {
float: right;
display: block;
background: url(images/not-interested.jpg) no-repeat top center;
margin-right: 40px;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
}

a.hidedislikedimgon {
float: right;
display: block;
background: url(images/not-interested.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
margin-right: 40px;
height: 30px;
width: 150px;
}
```

I think the code speaks for itself. I have to say this problem is completely unexpected!

Comment: Do you have any css that we can see?  The jQuery looks fine, as demonstrated in http://jsfiddle.net/P2MPY/

Comment: I guess you can see why I'm so perplexed about my problem.

Comment: yeah, very odd.  Do you have it on a server so the world+dog can see?

Comment: I managed to solce the problem by defining the width and height of the #mastercontrols. Why this is necessary though is beyond me.